# Spring boot doesn't use jackson properties on application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch

I´m using Spring Boot 2.3.1, I included some Jackson properties in `application.properties` file, but I think they are not being applied when I get the response.

The dates are deserialized incorrectly (as an array), and the properties are not in order.

Is there anything that I´m doing wrong?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>es.com.dgtnt.moderm.elastic</groupId>
    <artifactId>mam-apiRest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>API MAM</name>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- varios -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-20200106.122158-50</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-20200106.122158-43</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger-common</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-20200106.122158-51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-20200106.122158-51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-20200106.122158-51</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
## Jackson
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-with-zone-id=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false
spring.jackson.mapper.sort-properties-alphabetically=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Madrid
```

```json
{
    "body": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": ""
            }
        ],
        "content": [],
        "page": {
            "size": 10,
            "totalElements": 0,
            "totalPages": 0,
            "number": 0
        }
    },
    "timestamp": [
        2020,
        11,
        12,
        18,
        16,
        30,
        816000000
    ],
    "message-response": "",
    "code-response": "200.00",
    "info-error": null
}
```

The application retrieves information from elasticsearch BD, the list of results is wrapped with a custom response structure ("body" property) and returned by the controller.

Comment: Could you please share the complete pom.xml of your boot project? And can you briefly explain what your app was doing, where, how you implement the response. Thanks

Comment: How have you defined the property of your Spring Data Elasticsearch entity class?

Comment: I've added more details as requested. 
The entity is defined by a bean with spring-data-elasticsearch annotations. The list of entities is wrapped only with a bean.
I think the default objectMapper instantiated by Spring is not being used to serialize the response. Thanks.

Comment: please show the entity definition; Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use Jackson, but needs the correct @Field annotations on the date field. The question is wether this happens between Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch or when Spring Data Rest is returning an entity that was correctly retrieved from Elasticsearch before being passed out.

Comment: wait - the timestamp property is *not* stored and retrieved from Elasticsearch?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch it was my firts thought, but was my fault, I left an "@EnableWebMvc" annotation in a configuration class, this annotation modifies de autoconfigure behavior in Spring to configure manually some aspects of the framework, like the json mapper. Thanks for your interest. [SOLUTION]